# django-channels databinding on model.save()

Tags: django, django-channels

I have a channels app that is using databinding. When changes are made with django admin they are being pushed to the web as expected. I have loop set up on a socket connection to do some long polling on a gpio unit and update the db, these changes are not being pushed to the web. Channels documentation says:

Signals are used to power outbound binding, so if you change the values of a model outside of Django (or use the .update() method on a QuerySet), the signals are not triggered and the change will not be sent out. You can trigger changes yourself, but you’ll need to source the events from the right place for your system.

How do I go about triggering these changes, as it happens with admin?

Thanks and please let me know if this is to vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant low-level code is in [lines 121-187](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/1.1.6/channels/binding/base.py#L121-L187) of `channels/binding/base.py` (at least in version 1.1.6).  That's where the signals are received and processed.  It involves a few different things, such as keeping track of which groups to send the messages to.  So it's a little involved, but you can probably tease out how to do it, looking at that code.

The steps involved are basically:

- Find the right groups for the client
- Format your message in the same way that the databinding code would (see [this section of the docs](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#websocket-multiplexing))
- Send the message to all the relevant groups you found in step 1.

Alternatively, you might consider using a REST API such that the socket code submits a POST to the API (which would create a database record via the ORM in the normal way) rather than directly creating database records.  Your signals will happen automatically in that case.  `djangorestframework` (server-side) and `requests` (client-side, if you're using python for the long-polling code) are your friends if you want to go that way, for sure.  If you're using another language for the long-polling client, there are many equivalent packages for REST API client work.

Good luck!